# Using QThread as receiver and sender

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

How can i get a worker thread to receive my data, modify it and emit it back. In my example i have everything running except sending the data to thread. Is there a way to do it via signals? I could use a Queue and a put/get but is there a solution to get a signal from main-thread to worker-thread?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QObject, QSize, pyqtSignal, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QToolBar, QAction
import sys, queue
import time

class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 600))

        toolbar = QToolBar("Toolbar")
        con = QAction("Connect", self)
        con.triggered.connect(self.connect)
        discon = QAction("Disconnect", self)
        discon.triggered.connect(self.disconnect)

        toolbar.addAction(con)
        toolbar.addAction(discon)
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)
        
        self.thread = None 
        self.counter = 0

    def connect(self):
        print("Connect")
        self.data = queue.Queue()
        self.thread = MyWorker(self.data)
        self.thread.back.connect(lambda count: self.DataFromWorker(count))
        self.thread.start()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.dataToWorker)
        self.timer.start(100)

    def disconnect(self):
        print("disconnect")
        if self.timer.isActive:
            self.timer.stop()

        if self.thread and self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.terminate()

    def dataToWorker(self):
        print("Send data to Worker")
        self.counter += 1
        self.data.put(self.counter)
        ###

    def DataFromWorker(self, count):
        print("Received data from Worker")
        print(count)


class MyWorker(QThread):
    back = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.data = data
        
    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                ###
                count = self.data.get(block=True, timeout=1)
                count += 10
                self.back.emit(count)
            except:
                pass
            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Test()
    win.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

**Edit:** I edited the code above, since the example wasn't that clear. The question is, how can i emit a singal from the main thread to the worker. In the example i use a queue but is there a better way to do it with signals?

Comment: `self.thread.back.connect(lambda count: self.DataFromWorker(count))` is changed to   `self.thread.back.connect(self.DataFromWorke)`

Comment: emit will transfer the value to the `count` of  `self.DataFromWorke`.

Comment: @dudulu I don't know how this should help me because self.DataFromWorker is already working. The question is how can i send the data to my worker-thread?

Answer (score 0):

Because my English is not good and I don't understand the problem very well, according to your instructions, You want to send the value to Qthread, right?

```py
class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 600))

        toolbar = QToolBar("Toolbar")
        con = QAction("Connect", self)
        con.triggered.connect(self.connect)
        discon = QAction("Disconnect", self)
        discon.triggered.connect(self.disconnect)

        toolbar.addAction(con)
        toolbar.addAction(discon)
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)
        self.data = list()
        self.thread = None
        self.counter = 0

    def connect(self):
        print("Connect")
        self.thread = MyWorker(self.data)
        self.thread.back.connect(self.DataFromWorker)
        self.thread.start()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.dataToWorker)
        self.timer.start(100)

    def disconnect(self):
        print("disconnect")
        if self.timer.isActive:
            self.timer.stop()

        if self.thread and self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.terminate()

    def dataToWorker(self):
        print("Send data to Worker")
        self.counter += 5
        self.data.append(self.counter)
        ###

    def DataFromWorker(self, count):
        print("Received data from Worker")
        print(count)


class MyWorker(QThread):
    back = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                ###
                count = self.data.pop(0)
                count += 10
                print(count)
                self.back.emit(count)
                time.sleep(1)
            except:
                pass
```

You can use Queue, I don't know if there is a signal method, according to your use of Queue, I will do this.

Comment: I edited the code and the qeustion. I hope it makes it more clear

Comment: You can use `Queue` or `List` or `Dict`. I usually send values using `List` or `Dict`. I haven't used the signal transmission method.

Comment: You can use Queue, I don't know if there is a signal method, people around me who use `Qt` do it.

Comment: I only use Queue if I want to share data under different processes.

Comment: But when i use a list im not thread-save anymore or am i wrong? For my example that doesn't matter but overall i search for a thread-save solution

Comment: I don't know what is the definition of your disappearance. I think Thread has been doing things.

Comment: Hi progS, did you find a solution for passing data to the qthread?